# Best way to add a string XML snippet into an XML document?

Tags: c#, xml

this may have been asked before, but I could not find it.

Suppose I have an XML element

```
XMLElement nd = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Node");
```

Now, I would like to add a child to nd with a full XML snippet I get from some other function, like this:

```
nd.AppendChild("<a1><a2></a2></a1>");
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nb.InnerXML = "<a1><a2></a2></a1>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The way above is not the "Best" way to do this.  The  elements are nodes and should be created and added in that fashion. (Not real code, close).

```
XMLElement nd = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Node");
XMLElement a1 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Node");
XMLElement a2 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Node");

//Add the node name etc.

nd.AppendChild(a1);
nd.AppendChild(a2);
```

It is not good to use "<a1>" strings.  What if the namespace changes?  What about special characters, don't want to process them yourself, right?